# How to create custom transitions for the VSE via addons?

Tags: python, add-on, video-sequence-editor

The VSE already has some built in transitions, such as the Wipe and Cross transitions, so I'm wondering if it's possible for me to add my own using the add-ons system in Blender. I don't mind if I need to wrap some C or C++ code into the add-on.

[image: Built-in transitions in Blender]

Mask effects aren't good enough for my needs, because the transitions I want to make require something more complex.

Is something like this even possible? I took a quick look at the source code and couldn't find anything that'd help me, but maybe someone else knows better than me.

Comment: IDK virtually anything about the source code, but you can construct your own transitions with the 3D view and an orthographic camera if needed.

Comment: You should ask a question like that at the vse dev chat: https://blender.chat/channel/vse 
If you need to do the transitions in the 3d space, you could, in an add-on, export the frames needed for the transition, use them as textures on 3d objects in a new scene, do some animation of the objects in 3d space, and then add this scene as a scene strip into the sequencer, overlapping the transition area. If it is just 2d moving stuff in and out, using 2.93+ has addition options for transformations in the strip sidebar panel. These can be animated.

Comment: You may want to check out blender artists' VSE section: https://blenderartists.org/t/video-sequence-editor-news-add-ons/1188770  perhaps one of the existing add-ons does what you want.